# Impala SQL Stockpiling Algorithm

Tags: sql, time-series, impala

I have prescription drug data that has a prescription date and the number of days supplied for that prescription.  I am trying estimate actually drug intake dates which can be different then prescription date if people (1) refill their prescription before their current prescription is done or (2) they lost their current prescription and so need a refill.

Below is sample data for 1 patient:

```
| patient_id | rx_start_date | days_supply |
|------------|---------------|-------------|
| 1          | 1/10/2013     | 3           |
| 1          | 1/11/2013     | 3           |
| 1          | 1/14/2013     | 3           |
```

Without adjusting for stockpiling the end dates are calculated as rx_start_date + days_supply - 1 see:

```
| patient_id | rx_start_date | days_supply | rx_end_date |
|------------|---------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1          | 1/10/2013     | 3           | 1/12/2013   |
| 1          | 1/11/2013     | 3           | 1/13/2013   |
| 1          | 1/14/2013     | 3           | 1/16/2013   |
```

As you can see the start date for the 2nd prescription is overlapped by the first prescription.  If we assume that they filled their prescription early then the actual intake date for the 2nd prescription should start on 1/13/2013. But moving the end date of the 2nd prescription causes an overlap over the 3rd prescription and so that must be moved as well. See the expected resulting table below:

```
| patient_id | rx_start_date | days_supply | rx_end_date |
|------------|---------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1          | 1/10/2013     | 3           | 1/12/2013   |
| 1          | 1/13/2013     | 3           | 1/15/2013   |
| 1          | 1/16/2013     | 3           | 1/18/2013   |
```

The other case is we might say if the current prescription overlaps the next one by more than 50% than we assume they lost their prescription and the 2nd prescription start date is the actual intake date.  This means though that we need to truncate the current prescription to end when the 2nd one starts.

The algorithm is relatively simple using a non-sql iterative solution but I'm having trouble with a generic sql solution since adjusting dates at time X could potentially cause a cascading effect that adjust many other dates.  I'm using Impala SQL so recursive CTE's are not an option and I'd like this to work on other databases so database specific functions are not ideal either.

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you what you are looking for, so long as there are no gaps in the treatment regime:

```
with aggs as (select d1.patient_id, d1.rx_start_dt, sum(ds.days_supply) days_supply, min(ds.rx_start_dt) + sum(ds.days_supply) - 1 end_dt 
          from drugs d1
          inner join drugs ds
            on ds.patient_id = d1.patient_id and ds.rx_start_dt <= d1.rx_start_dt
          group by d1.patient_id, d1.rx_start_dt)
select patient_id, coalesce(lag(end_dt+1) over (partition by patient_id order by rx_start_dt),rx_start_dt) start_dt, end_dt
from aggs;
```

Using the given sample data, this gives as output:

```
ID  Start       End
1   2013-01-10  2013-01-12 
1   2013-01-13  2013-01-15 
1   2013-01-16  2013-01-18
```

This was tested on Oracle, but all functions used appear to also be available in impala so should work there too.